# heroku: Node version not specified in package.json

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm trying to push my back-end and front-end with **git push heroku HEAD:master** and getting such **error**:

[image]

**What causes this error?**

Here you can check my package.json file:

[image]

Comment: Have you followed a specific tutorial and can you share this?

Comment: I was following this tutorial (only for deploying my project) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71wSzpLyW9k

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: You have a typo: instead of `"engines"`, your `package.json` says `"enigines"`, with an extra `i`.